# Select result of where clause

Tags: c#, linq

Take this method f.e.:

```
public static Function Parse(string codeAndData)
{
    return (from factory in factories
            where factory.Parse(codeAndData) != null
            select factory.Parse(codeAndData)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

As you can see, `factory.Parse(codeAndData)` is called twice, which is bad practice. Therefore we could write it like this:

```
public static Function Parse(string codeAndData)
{
    Function function = null;
    return (from factory in factories
            where (function = factory.Parse(codeAndData)) != null
            select function).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But the above doesn't seem very elegant to me. Is there a better LINQ alternative to this?

Comment: do the select before the where

Comment: Your second option is _bad_. You should avoid side effects like that. If you decided to parallelize that operation, you could wind up with a mess on your hands.

Comment: @JLRishe it felt bad, that's the reason of my question :)

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Yeah, I figured that much. Just making sure it was said explicitly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy with the method chaining syntax:

```
return factories.Select(f => f.Parse(codeAndData))
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);
```

With the comprehension syntax, you can accomplish this with `let`:

```
return (from factory in factories
        let p = factory.Parse(codeAndData)
        where p != null
        select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since you're already mixing FirstOrDefault with the comprehension syntax, you could also do this:

```
return (from factory in factories
        select factory.Parse(codeAndData))
       .FirstOrDefault(p => p != null);
```

but that seems kind of a silly alternative to the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using assignments, you can do the selection procedure before:

```
public static Function Parse(string codeAndData) {
    return (from factory in factories
            select factory.Parse(codeAndData)
            ).Where(y => y != null).FirstOrDefault();
}
```